# Xcode 5 | Background | Not Working

Tags: ios, xcode, background, preview, beta

Okay, I just downloaded Xcode 5...
Previously, I was able to edit the background from the attributes inspector. Now, I have to implement this to change my background color:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Is it even possible to use the previous method of editing a view controller's background color with the attributes inspector using Xcode 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Xcode, when you select the view of the view controller (not the view controller itself) you have backgroundColor in the Attributes inspector. In Xcode 5 it's the same as it is in Xcode 4, just make sure you are selecting viewController's view :)

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing the distinction. I'm just learning obj-c in xcode5 and can't change my view's background color.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/v32qF4v.png - as you can see on the left, I've selected the view, and on the right is where the background color is changing